# How do i make the query dynamic

Tags: java, android

Hi trying to make the query dynamic.
Each button in the app menu list has a button id I have no control on the button id as the database is populated from remote server.

I can get the button id but how do I pass this into a query?

```
public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getAllDailys() {
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> locationsList;
    locationsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    String ButtonId = intent.getStringExtra("buttonId");
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM locations WHERE id_button =  ?", ButtonId;
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put("id", cursor.getString(0));
            map.put("locations", cursor.getString(2));
            map.put("checks", cursor.getString(3));
            locationsList.add(map);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    database.close();
    return locationsList;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Change this:

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM locations WHERE id_button =  ?", ButtonId;
```

To:

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM locations WHERE id_button = \'" + ButtonId + "\'";
```

Comment: I downvoted you for building SQL by hand instead of using parameterized queries.